# Sync data near real time between 2 databases on 2 different servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, high-availability

One of my clients asked me to find a solution that can sync the 2 databases in near real time. Basically, they try to pull the data through linked server from server A through server B, but since server A goes down they can't pull the data as the database is not available, so they need some near real time data available to be queried even if the source is not available for sometime. Also, something that I forgot to add the database should always be on server A.

- SQL version - SQL 2012 SP3 (both server A and server B)
- RAM - 32 GB

So essentially, Server A's database is the production DB, and Server B's database is used as a "read-only" copy - no changes go through server B.  If Server A goes down, then Server B is up-to-date, or almost so.  However, Server B is not intended to become the live production DB at that point - it's just available to reference the data until Server A comes back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make a copy of the data from server 'A' on server 'B' that can be can be used as reference data.  The data on server 'B' should be refreshed from server 'A' as often as possible.  Presumably, you don't need to make changes to the data once it is on server 'B'.

I'd recommend using replication to update server 'B' on a schedule; if server 'A' is down, no replication will happen, however once server 'A' comes back online, server 'B' will be brought up to date at the next scheduled replication event.